# Почему при работе сеттера не происходит создание нового св-ва?

Tags: javascript, объекты, set

В первом случае создается объект, затем создается его внутреннее св-во.

```js
obj = {};
obj.sister = 'Fiona';

console.log(obj.sister); //Fiona
```

Второй пример практически такой же самый. Единственное отличие - использование сеттера для создаваемого св-ва.

```js
let obj = {
    surname: 'Li',
    set name(val) {
        this.fullName = val + ' ' + this.surname;
    }
};
obj.name = 'Eva'; //срабатывает метод set

console.log(obj.name); //undefined
```

Почему так? Почему не происходит создание св-ва?

Comment: Вoпрос некорректен и вреден, т.к. свойство по факту ***создается*** (это легко проверить, например, вызовом статического метода `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
let obj = {
  surname: 'Li',
  set name(val) {
    this.fullName = val + ' ' + this.surname;
  },
  get name() {
    return 'Потому что надо добавить getter'
  }
};
obj.name = 'Eva'; //срабатывает метод set

console.log(obj.name)
```

[На этой странице](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) можно найти, что совместное использование `value` и `setter/getter` является ошибкой. Поэтому либо используем как в первом случае(примера), либо `setter/getter`.

Часто используется один `getter`, когда значение может быть вычисляемым и/или оно не может(не должно) быть "записываемым".